# Why can't neural networks be applied to preference learning problems?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, papers

In section 6.1 of the paper [Neural Networks in Economics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249900701_Neural_Networks_in_Economics), the authors say

> this leads to the problem, that no risk can be formulated which shall be minimized by a Neural Network learning algorithm.

So, why can't neural networks be applied to *preference learning* problems?

See sections 6.0 of [the same paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249900701_Neural_Networks_in_Economics) for a definition of preference learning.

Comment: Please, next time, do not assume that the readers of your post are familiar with what you are writing, so provide more context in the post.